# A gap in IUP dropdown lists

Tags: iup

Dropdown lists in IUP for Windows contain **a superfluous gap** after the last element if the number of elements is sufficient to warrant a scrollbar (which is five or more).

Is this something I can change?

#### Example

```
dropdown = DIALOG[TITLE=dropdown.led](
  HBOX[CMARGIN=10x10,CGAP=10](
    LIST[VALUE=3, 1=я, 2=ты, 3=оно, 4=мы, 5=вы, 6=они, DROPDOWN=YES](do_nothing),
    LIST[VALUE=3, 1=ik, 2=je, 3=hij, 4=we, DROPDOWN=YES](do_nothing)
  )
)
```

[image: Two animated dropdown lists in a dialog with ill-encoded Russian and well-encoded Dutch pronouns and a superfluous gap at the end of the Russian list]

#### All questions that pertain to this particular example:

1. [How do I get access to GUI elements in a IUP dialog loaded from a LED file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449619)
2. [How can I make Russian letters visible in a IUP dialog loaded from a LED file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449994)
3. **[A gap in IUP dropdown lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450141) (current)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is dependent on the VISIBLEITEMS attribute which default is 5.

Comment: It’s a good thing to know and a workaround that works. However, an ideal solution would let the user *both* have a scrollbar (i.e. a number of list elements > `VISIBLEELEMENTS`) and no gap after the last element. It’s not a big deal, only a small cosmetic defect. Therefore I’ll accept this answer as a solution if nothing better appears.

Comment: As far as I remember that is a system behavior. Notice that IUP uses the native Win32 list in Windows.